# Value of pointer C

Tags: c, pointers, printf, dev-c++

I have one question!I am thinking about the value of the pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define dd NULL
enum {ee=1} ff=ee+17;

int main()
{

float hh[]={10,4,(float)('b'-'d')};

static float *ii=dd;

hh[0]+=6/4;
ii=&hh[2]-1;
*ii=ii[0]+3;
ii[-1]=(*(hh+1))+2;
hh[2]=*(++ii)*2;
*ii=(hh[0]==4);
printf("%f",ii);
```

Why value of pointer ii = 0? It shouldn't be still number of memory cell?

Comment: `printf("%f",ii);` is a nonsensical function call. The behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hh[0]+=6/4; /* hh[0] = 11.000000 */
ii=&hh[2]-1; /* *ii =  hh[2 - 1] = 4.000000 */
*ii=ii[0]+3; /* *ii = 4 + 3 = 7.000000 */
ii[-1]=(*(hh+1))+2; /* hh[0] = h[1] + 2 = 9.000000 */
hh[2]=*(++ii)*2; /* hh[2] = *ii = hh[2] * 2 = ((float)('b'-'d')) * 2 = -4.000000 */
*ii=(hh[0]==4); /* *ii = 0 */
```

*ii == 0; because hh[0] != 4

Comment: I know that *ii == 0; because hh[0] != 4 but why ii = 0?

Comment: ii != 0;

Print its address with this : `printf("%u",(unsigned int)ii);`

Comment: If the value of the pointer `ii` was `0`, you would segmentation fault while trying to access to `*ii`; So yes `ii` is not pointing to 0 but to an address;

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer!!

Answer (score 2):

You tried to print a pointer with %f, which prints doubles. Incorrect int-float matching in varargs is an obscure path to undefined behavior. Use %p for pointers in printf.